# How to make optional parameter value in ActionResult method in Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, actionresult

When user click the button, it will redirect to another controller action method with or without parameter value

```
<button type="button" onclick="location.href='http://localhost/ProjectName/Customer/Details'" >Go to Details</button>

<button type="button" onclick="location.href='http://localhost/ProjectName/Customer/Details?name=xxx'" >View Details</button>
```

**CustomerController**

```
    public ActionResult Details()   // i don't know how to pass optional parameter value
    {
        // some code ...
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: If you are using c# 4 or greater you can use optional parameter, just declare the parameter and give a value like this yourController(int param1 = 0), then you will be able to send or not send this parameter

Comment: @AntonioAvndañoDuran in my case I am using string. I already saw for integer. it is showing no error for integer. but not for string variable

Comment: maybe will be useful if you update your example code and question to ask about strings solutions

Answer (score 1):

If you are using c# 4.0 or higher, you can use this:

```
public ActionResult Details(string name = "xxx")
  {
    // some code ...
    return View();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you may use this Initializing parameter with empty value,

`

```
 public ActionResult Details(string Name = string.Empty)
  {
    return View();
  }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

As string is nullable itself, so you can use it in parameter and it will be optional, then you will only check for `null` values within it. For example:

```
public ActionResult Details(string optionalParameter)
{
     //Check it now for value
     if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(optionalParameter))
     {
        //some code if it is empty
     }
     else
     {
        //some code if it is not empty
     }

    // some code ...
    return View();
}
```